# Handling all windows mouse click events in C#

Tags: c#, windows, mouseevent

My Mouse has started to double click on single clicks, and I know this is a somewhat common issue. I am wanting to handle all mouse click events to fix this issue in software. I know "LowLevelMouseProc" has some decent control, but through many Google searches, I just can't seem to find what I need. There are two main functions I need is.

1. My application to be the first in the "CallNextHookEx" chain (The Main issue).
2. To be able to deny or force button state changes for on mouse press, and on mouse release.

and I do know about the "Left Mouse Button Fix" program, but it does not handle drags after a phantom click(after Mouse Release it does not allow for Mouse Press)

Comment: *"My Mouse has started to double click on single clicks, and I know this is a somewhat common issue."* Err, what? How is this a common problem?

Comment: As the device gets older, you will start to bend the spring inside the button giving you non solid clicks. there was 2 sets of Logitech devices prone to this, over %10 after a couple months apparently. and after several years most mice are able to get this issue.

Comment: Wouldn't it work to just increase the double-click time? If it's a broken spring that's causing this, it has to be sending two click messages in rapid succession. Just tell Windows not to interpret those as a double click. Or, you know, by a new mouse. They're less than $10. Not worth the headache of writing software.

Comment: windows only allows to to lower the max time for a double click, not increase the time for a minimum time for a double click and yes, I am aware that I can get a new mouse for cheap, but that is not why I am here, I was looking for insight on a software solution, not a solution my mother could have told me. Also never hurts to get some more practice in on a hobby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that to filter *everything* the mouse puts through would take a colossal amount of time to fix a problem that will only get worse.

I know that this isn't a programmer's fix to the problem, but I had a similar trouble. I took an afternoon and fixed my mouse using some instructions I found on the web. I couldn't find the ones I used, but [these](http://www.instructables.com/id/Repair-mouse-with-double-click-problem/) are great. I would suggest that you have plenty of light and a magnifying glass.

Door number 3 is just buy a new mouse...

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at that tutorial, I was going to try that out if I could not get this working properly.

Comment: If you do decide to do it, I hope it works out well for you. Just remember that the springs are _tiny_. I almost lost one of mine, but that was due to not having enough room to do it in.